# Write to Windows Event Viewer from log file

Tags: windows, events, logging

I have a log file "**logs.log**" that include the status of one of the applications, and I want to write these logs in Windows Events Viewer.

the output in that file as below:

```
24/01/2019 16:33:26   app(12744.13964) <SYSTEM> SERVICE.app.Activity: Stopping service...
```

Is there any way to write them in Windows Events Viewer?

BR

Comment: Some more information is needed. Are you trying to import existing log files or are you trying to modify your applications to write the log messages directly to the event log. If so what language is your application written in.

Comment: Hi Nick, i have existing log files and I would like to write those logs messages directly to the event log. Thanks

Comment: You could use Powershell to load your existing log messages one at the time and then write them into the Windows Event Log using the [Write-EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/write-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) command